# Anaconda installed by HomeBrew "Path not writable or missing."

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, homebrew, homebrew-cask

After install anaconda by "brew cask install anaconda", commands always warn like this

```
WARNING conda.core.envs_manager:register_env(52): Unable to register environment. Path not writable or missing.
  environment location: /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/test
  registry file: /Users/**/.conda/environments.txt
done
```

Answer (score 11):

May it is a bug of homebrew, after install anaconda, brew will

1. change the owner of /usr/local/anaconda3
2. change the privilege of /usr/local/anaconda3 and ~/.conda/environments.txt

I think it omit the owner of  ~/.conda/environments.txt, when I "ls -al ~/.conda"

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root     staff    21 Dec 11 14:54 environments.txt
```

the owner is root, what I need to do is

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.conda
```

it will solve the problem.